# Airport Express as extension

Tags: network, wifi, time-capsule, airport

I have an Airport time capsule as a main wireless, I add an Airport Extreme and a Airport Express as extension of my network. All of them have the same connection name.
Problem: the connection in the rooms where the extended devices are placed is too slow...
Is there a way to check the internet speed of each of the devices? 
The one with ethernet cable that is the main the speed is very good, but the others :(
Any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about checking the speed of the AirPort Express, or are you just trying to check the speeds of the devices connected to the extended network? If you are trying to check the speed on the devices, just go to speedtest.net.

Comment: Sorry CSstudent I want a way to check the speed of the wireless extension like the airport express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is similar to [this question](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/testing-airport-extreme-speed-or-checking-is-type-n-connected.450231/) on MacRumors. Try using AirPort Utility to check the speeds you are getting from the AirPort Express. Go to AirPort Utility -> Base Station -> Logs and Statistics -> Wireless Clients. Then, check the box called "Tx Rate." You'll see 130-270 for 802.11n, and < 56 for 802.11g. This will tell you what type of connection you are getting on your extended networks--i.e., 802.11a/b/g/n/ac. If you are getting very slow speeds, you may not be getting the speed you are getting from the TimeCapsule. Also, check out [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120451/airport-express-very-weak-connection) on StackExchange for determining the performance of your wired network.

Hope this helps.